# Group by Rating type?

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have two tables:

ab_message

- user_id
- title
- content
- question

and ab_message_rating:

- id
- user_id
- message_id
- created_at
- updated_at

`ab_message` is in a OneToMany Relation with `ab_message_rating`. Every Entry in `ab_message_rating` has 1, 2 or 3 as rating value.

So i want to select in one query the Message an all related Tables Entries. The Key is, that i need in this query rating to be counted BY value.

For Example the Result schuld be:

> Message abc has 5 entries of rating 1, 7 entries of rating 2, and 10
>   entries of rating 3

how to do that in a query? Something like Group By and A Join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Title, Content, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rating = 'Rating 1' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) 'Rating 1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rating = 'Rating 2' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) 'Rating 2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN Rating = 'Rating 3' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) 'Rating 3'
FROM    
(
    SELECT  a.ID, a.Title, a.Content,
            b.Rating, COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    Message a
            LEFT JOIN Rating b
                ON a.ID = b.MessageID
    GROUP BY a.ID, a.Title, a.Content, b.Rating
) r
GROUP BY ID, Title, Content
```

Sample Result:

```
╔════╦═══════════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║     TITLE     ║ CONTENT  ║ RATING 1 ║ RATING 2 ║ RATING 3 ║
╠════╬═══════════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ Lost Prophets ║ CONTENT1 ║        1 ║        5 ║        7 ║
║  2 ║ Cannibal      ║ CONTENT2 ║        3 ║        4 ║        6 ║
║  3 ║ Sigbin        ║ CONTENT3 ║        4 ║        4 ║        1 ║
╚════╩═══════════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Hi JW, i tried to adapt your query to my scheme but i got: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.rating' in 'field list'

here is the query:

Comment: SELECT id, title, content, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.rating = '1' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) '1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.rating = '2' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) '2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN b.rating = '3' THEN totalCount ELSE NULL END) '3'
FROM    
(
    SELECT  a.id, a.title, a.content,
            b.rating, COUNT(*) totalCount
    FROM    ab_message a
            LEFT JOIN ab_message_rating b
                ON a.id = b.message_id
    GROUP BY a.id, a.title, a.content, b.rating
) r
GROUP BY id, title, content

Comment: sorry try it again, `b.` should be removed.

Comment: ah wow this works fine :) thank you.. do you have good reading stuff to improve sql skills?

Comment: you're welcome. `:D` what your email add? i'll send you an ebook :D

Comment: can you please send me the book? :]

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4cb115/2) is not very efficient or pretty, but it will be functional:

```
select concat('Message "', m.title , '" has ', 
   cast((select count(*) 
        from Table_Rating r 
        where r.message_id = m.id 
        and rating = 1) as char),
   ' entries of rating 1, ',
   cast((select count(*) 
        from Table_Rating r 
        where r.message_id = m.id 
        and rating = 2) as char),
   ' entries of rating 2, and ',
   cast((select count(*) 
        from Table_Rating r 
        where r.message_id = m.id 
        and rating = 3) as char),
   ' entries of rating 3') as FullMessage
from Table_Message m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'Message '+ m.title + ' has ' + 
    -- ISNULL(z.Rating1/2/3,0) because z.Rating1/2/3 could be NULL (see OUTER APPLY + Table_Rating may not have rows)
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ISNULL(z.Rating1,0)) + 'entries of rating 1, ' +  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ISNULL(z.Rating2,0)) + 'entries of rating 2, and '+
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ISNULL(z.Rating3,0)) +  'entries of rating 3' AS Description
FROM Table_Message tm
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT y.[1] AS Rating1, y.[2] AS Rating2, y.[3] AS Rating3
    FROM (
        -- This query will generate 0, 1, 2 or 3 rows because of GROUP BY r.Rating
        SELECT r.Rating, COUNT(*) as Cnt 
        FROM Table_Rating r 
        WHERE r.message_id = m.id 
        GROUP BY r.Rating
    ) x
    -- The PIVOT operator will transponse (it converts rows into columns) the source rows (alias x) into just one row with 3 columns:
    -- [1] = COUNT for Rating 1, [2] = COUNT for Rating 2, [3] = COUNT for Rating 3
    PIVOT ( MAX(x.Cnt) FOR x.Rating IN ([1], [2], [3]) ) y
) z
```

Comment: I wouldn't class this as an answer in it's current form. Please add an explanation and/or more detail so it's obvious what's changed. Being more descriptive also helps future visitors understand how to fix their problem.

Comment: @JamWaffles: I added comments to my solution. If you have questions then feel free to ask.